# If a sequence occurs then a subsequence occurs within it in System-Verilog assertions

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I want to say:
"if the sequence `A` occurs then the sequence `B` occurs within that sequence". How can I do this?

I would have thought I could use the assertion:

```
assert property (@(posedge clk) (A |-> (B within A));
```

but this doesn't seem to work for my example.

I've read that:

> The linear sequence is said to match along a finite interval of consecutive clock ticks provided the first boolean expression evaluates to true at the first clock tick, the second boolean expression evaluates to true at the second clock tick, and so forth, up to and including the last boolean expression evaluating to true at the last clock tick.

but i suspect that the clock tick passed to the otherside of the `|->` the last clock tick when I want it to be the first.

My particular example is an accumulator which I expect to overflow if I add enough positive numbers, so I want `A = (input == 1)[*MAX_SIZE]` and `B = (output == 0)`, so here `B` is a sequence of length 1, I don't know if that causes problems.

I'm very new to system-verilog so it maybe that it's some other part of my code which is going wrong but I've not seen this example done anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the consequent in the `|->` operator is started once `A` has already matched. What you want is to look into the past: "once I've seen `A`, have I seen `B within A`?".

You could use the `triggered` property of a sequence to do this:

```
sequence b_within_a;
  @(posedge clk)
    B within A;
endsequence

assert property (@(posedge clk) A |-> b_within_a.triggered);
```

The `b_within_a` sequence will match exactly at the end of `A`, of course, if `B` also happened, which is when the `triggered` property will evaluate to `1`.

Note that the `b_within_a` sequence has its clock defined specifically. This is a requirement from the LRM, otherwise you won't be allowed to call `triggered` on it.

Comment: What if `B within A` gets completed before `A` gets completed? I mean that   `B within A` = B should be inside A and hence it will be completed as soon as `B` transitions from `1` to `0`, while `A` is still active, but not yet completed.

Comment: Then you haven't satisfied the `within A` part and the sequence will not match yet.

Comment: Yes that's true, because as per LRM `B within A` means `(1[*0:$] ##1 B ##1 1[*0:$]) intersect A`.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I needed to add `@(posedge clk)` into the declaration of my sequence, until then i was getting `This sequence method does not have a clock.` I got the idea from another one of @TudorTimi  posts: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876386/reset-awareness-when-using-sequence-triggered-in-assertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876386/reset-awareness-when-using-sequence-triggered-in-assertion)

Comment: @R.Mckemey That was oversight on my part. The LRM indeed requires you to explicitly define a clock if you want to use a sequence's `triggered` property.